# Laravel/HTML date table columns provided empty

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send data (date) from input to DB and I've tried literally every way I could imagine and no one worked. But when I check sent data with dd(); it is showing the right data. Always is showing this error:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'pocetak' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-08-04 14:53:11, 2020-08-04 14:53:11))
```

DB TABLE:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->date('pocetak');
        $table->date('kraj');
        $table->float('ukupno');
        $table->string('radiliste');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

BLADE:

```
<div class="card-body">
        <form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="post">
            @csrf

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pocetak">Početak rada</label>
                <input type="date" name="pocetak" value="{{ old('pocetak') }}" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="kraj">Završetak rada</label>
                <input type="date" name="kraj" value="{{ old('kraj') }}" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ukupno">Ukupno radno vrijeme</label>
                <input type="number" step="0.1" name="ukupno" value="{{ old('ukupno') }}" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="radiliste">Radilište</label>
                <input type="text" name="radiliste" value="{{ old('radiliste') }}" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="btn-posaljiIzvjestaj">Pošalji izvještaj</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

CONTROLLER (don't need validation etc.. just need to send and store data to DB):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Post::create([
        'pocetak' => $request->pocetak,
        'kraj' => $request->kraj,
        'ukupno' => $request->ukupno,
        'radiliste' => $request->radiliste
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('home');

}
```

**EDIT**

POST MODEL:

```
protected $fillable = ['pocetak, kraj, ukupno, radiliste'];

protected $dates = ['pocetak, kraj'];
```

Here you can see how does form looks like and on the side are shown table columns for every field.
https://prnt.sc/ttxb4k

And here is dd() output with some random data.
https://prnt.sc/ttxc11

Comment: What is the output for `dd($request)` inside store?

Comment: Your all input field are required on your SQL table. So you can't insert data with **blank/null** value

Comment: @STA I know I cant input blank data but when I go dd() it shows that data should be sent correctly. That is the part that is confusing me :)

Comment: @JulianMendez it just displays field name and the value that I've inserted in that input. Everything looks just fine.

Comment: Sorry about this question, but did you run the migration to create those database fields, right?

Comment: @JulianMendez ofc :D

Comment: try with `Post::create($request->all())`

Comment: @JulianMendez dont work either same error

Comment: I've found the issue... LOL look at this line of code ... protected $fillable = ['pocetak, kraj, ukupno, radiliste']; .... every single field name should be inside ' ' .... I've by mistake just put opening ' and closing ' xD

Answer (score 1):

in your **Post** Model, make sure you have $fillable property with correct properties:

```
class Post extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['pocetak','kraj','ukupno','radiliste'];
....
}
```

Comment: forgot to post that too but I have covered mass assignment :D

Comment: then must be an empty input, you must be sure of $request->pocetak is not null

Comment: I've edited my question u can see there is dd() and all input fields with names etc.. :D

Comment: issue is here : protected $fillable = ['pocetak, kraj, ukupno, radiliste']; did not put every single one in its ' ' hahah